# How long can you stay with a tourist visa in Japan?

Tags: visas, japan, palestine-citizens

How long can I stay in Japan with a tourist visa?
Can I stay for 3 months for example?
'cause I'll be taking an entrance exam for some voice acting school, and I don't know if I'll be accepted or not, so I'll have to wait for 2 months or so before the actual school begin so that I can change it to a student visa if I was accepted, and I'm afraid that I can't stay in Japan with a tourist visa that long by Japanese laws.

I'm Palestinian.

Comment: @Rozan Al-Rajaby Are you sure you can apply for a study visa from within Japan? All the information I’ve seen states that you must apply from your country of residence eg https://www.japanvisitor.com/japan-travel/japan-study-visa

Comment: Thank you so much for warning me about it!
It has been really helpful, thank you so much
+I think the company which has the school I'm auditioning for is going to take care of the student visa, I am not really sure, but I heard that two Chinese people were studying at it so I believe I can do the same. I am going to contact  the school first and ask them about the details so I guess it'll be okay somehow

Answer (score 3):

Both no Visa required and Visa required tourists are allowed for 90 days in Japan.

There is an exception if you have 30 million yen and you and your spouse can stay in Japan for 1 year.

Source:
https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2221.html

Answer (score 0):

A tourist (V) visa allows you to stay for 90 days max, provided that you provide sufficient rationale. I have done a research visit to Japan before I came here, and I stayed for 78 days - I just showed the consulate that I'm visiting for research, and they approved me for 90 days without question. As long as you can prove sufficient funds, there is likely no problem for you to stay 2 months with a reason that seems quite valid.